# Handsome boys in heaven

Tags: homosexuality

While reading a detailed description of Sura Waqia I came across this ayat:
[image]

Without sparking a heated debate, why does Koran specifically stresses on the boys' youth and beauty and that they will be a pleasure to the people in  paradise. Youth and beauty maybe admirable but what about "be a pleasure to the people of paradise"?

Could it mean that homosexuality is test for homosexual in the world so a person suppressing his desire to please God will have these boys in heaven as reward?
 just as alcohol is haram but it becomes halal in heaven (off course it might be a different one).

Reference:
[Homosexuality in Islam](http://sbcvoices.com/what-does-the-koran-teach-about-homosexuality-in-paradise/) (*search the article for Abdel Hamid Kishk*)

Comment: You should put it as an answer instead. A very brief but a very interesting point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quran forbids or permits for this life,on the earth. We don't even know what we will face in the afterlife. Quran gives examples to us so maybe we can imagine some part of the afterlife. Therefore, this means rules for this life may not be necessarily operative or valid for the afterlife.

Answer (score 4):

This ayah only tells about servants,and being attractive/beautiful. So i really do not see that how being attractive, is directly connected to anything related to sexuality. I mean there are other reasons too, due to which people can prefer beautiful men. Beauty of man never means that they have to be used for sexual pleasure ,it can mean anything else besides sex too.

So, as there is absolutely NO mention of sexuality or sexual relations, but just word "beautiful", so this ayah cannot be used to hae this meanings.

Another point that "Mukhalladoon" means immortal.

and Allah knows the best

Answer (score -3):

In reality’s i will résume my claims
How much our lord will surpringly alow pure maters as a reward for his servents who endured with patience and worshiped him

Comment: This is really hard to read, and lacks some evidences to support your claims. Don't use numbers such as 3 for expressing ع but Latin letters or good transliteration such as 'ayn!

Comment: This is hard to read ,firstly my mothers tongue is Arabic , but don’t worry! I will proof read it and what evidence should you need. All I said we can not stop on some assumption without a said Hadith explaining the verse

Comment: Evidences are sources that support your claims be it from the Qur'an, sunnah or a book etc.

Comment: But I had put on evidence of my claims

Comment: This was a HUGE answer. OP, why did you edit it down to only this?